# Need to count only once in case statement

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to count only 1 even if condition is met for other records as well

using case statement to check condition

sample data
table a
**meeting_id**
1

```
table b
**meeting_id | attendee_id**
1, 10
1, 11
1, 12
1, 13

table c
**attendee_id | dept**
10, field sales
11, field sales
12, dmt
13, field sales



 select A.ACC_ID,
    TO_NUMBER(SUBSTRING(A.MONTH_NO,1,4)) AS YY,
    TO_NUMBER(SUBSTRING(A.MONTH_NO,5,6)) AS MM,
    sum(case when USER_INFO.DEPARTMENT='Field Sales' then 1 else 0 end) AS MEETING_WITH_SALE
    from "TABLE1" A LEFT JOIN "TABLE2" B
    ON (A.meeting_id=A.meeting_id) AND (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTRING(A.MONTH_NO,1,4))=YEAR(A.DATE_OF_MEETING)) AND (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTRING(A.MONTH_NO,5,6))=MONTH(A.DATE_OF_MEETING))
    LEFT JOIN "TABLE3" c ON A.attendee_id=c.attendee_id
    GROUP BY 1,2
```

expected result
meeting id 1 has 1 sales meeting because one/more of its attendee's are from sales dept

Comment: share sample data

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead!

Comment: @SahilGupta . . . What condition are you referring to?  Your question is incomplete.  Also, what you want for results is quite unclear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff please refer again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple options:

1) get a boolean saying whether the sum was 1 or higher, and convert it to int:

`(sum(case when USER_INFO.DEPARTMENT='Field Sales' then 1 else 0 end)>=1)::int)`

2) use `least` function:

`least(1,sum(case when USER_INFO.DEPARTMENT='Field Sales' then 1 else 0 end))`

3) use another case statement:

```
case 
    when sum(case when USER_INFO.DEPARTMENT='Field Sales' then 1 else 0 end)>1
    then 1 
    else 0
end
```

overall, it's just piping the aggregate that you had into scalar post-processing